# Does every smooth manifold carry a gaussian random field?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be an arbitrary smooth manifold of dimension $n$. For simplicity, let's assume that $M$ is boundary-less. Can we construct a gaussian random field on $M$?

If the result is not true for arbitrary $M$, is there a theorem that provides minimal assumptions on $M$ for which we always can find a gaussian random field?

Comment: The existence is certainly true for any manifold: just take a constant field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Robert Adler has written some books on Gaussian random fields that I enjoyed perusing.  For specific examples of Gaussian random fields that are guaranteed to exist on closed manifolds under minimal assumptions you could look at http://arxiv.org/abs/1207.6419 and the references therein.